# Correct way to declare ForeignKey in Django's Forms

Tags: python, django

I've got an error to POST data to DB Tables. I think i've made a mistake on how to declare my Models. When i want to submit my Form, this error appeared.

*Cannot assign "u'3'": "AerialFoto.index_id" must be a "No_index" instance.*

### Models.py

```
class AerialFoto(models.Model):
    AerialFoto_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    index_id = models.ForeignKey(No_index, null=True, blank=True)
    scale_id = models.ForeignKey(Scale, null=True, blank=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
    year_id = models.ForiegnKey(Year, null=True, blank=True)
    file_directory = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    gsd = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

### My Views.py

def submit_upload(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        year_id = form.cleaned_data['year_id']
        scale_id = form.cleaned_data['scale_id']
        index_id = form.cleaned_data['index_id']
        location_id = form.cleaned_data['location_id']
        size = form.cleaned_data['size']
        print index_id
          query = AerialFoto(year_id = year_id , scale_id = scale_id, index_id = index_id, location_id = location_id, size = size)
        query.save()
```

[The Result After Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2He8.jpg)

Comment: What is `UploadForm`? Why wouldn't you use a ModelForm?

Comment: UploadForm is my form in Forms.py

Comment: How to use ModelForm?

Answer (score 0):

**"AerialFoto.index_id" must be a "No_index" instance!**

You can write a crutch

```
index_id = No_index.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['index_id'])
```

but it is better to use the ModelForm

Comment: How to use ModelForm?

Answer (score 0):

To use model forms you need to make a modelform (difficult huh); this is done using something like the following:

```
# forms.py
class UploadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AerialFoto
        fields = ['year_id', 'scale_id', 'index_id', 'location_id', 'size']
```

The model form will need to be imported and used in your view something like this:

```
# views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
```

I have not tested this code so please do not come back and say "it does not work" its only as a boiler plate.

Comment: I use the method above but the data does not inserted into the table.. But when i'm using a crutch method i can POST my data into my table. Just that the result in my table was like this:-

index_idobjects, scale_idobjects, year_idobjects

Answer (score 0):

To use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) in order to create a form from model, you would have to:

```
class AerialPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AerialPhoto
        fields = ['year_id', 'scale_id', 'index_id', 'location_id', 'size']
```

Then in your view:

```
# ...
form = AerialPhotoForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: Its works! but the value display as an objects in my table.

Comment: I am glad it does, @IamMoon. I don't quite understand what you mean, but you can control the field widgets and the way data is displayed as you can with a regular form.

Comment: wait.. i edit my question and paste my print screen of admin. i don't know how to explain.

Comment: @IamMoon I would recommend you to post a new question and not to morph this question to something different.